# raw_input not working after while loop

Tags: python, raw-input

I have a question about the `raw_input` function.

I made a small number-guessing game as a small project, and if you don't want to play it states "goodbye". However, I have put it as a `raw_input` so the program only closes after you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The problem with this is that the program completely looks over the `raw_input` bit, whereas using `print("")` instead works.

Have I made a mistake anywhere? Here is the code:

```
import random
from random import randint
Number = 0
Guess = 0
while True:
    Decision = raw_input("Do you want to play a round of number guess?(Yes/No)")
    if Decision == "Yes":
        Number = randint(0,100)
        while True:
            Guess = input("What number will you guess?")
            if Guess == Number:
                print("Correct!")
                break
            if Guess > Number:
                print("Too big!")
            if Guess < Number:
                print("Too Small")
    elif Decision == "No":
        print("Oh well")
        break
    else:
        print("I'm not what that means...")
raw_input = ("Goodbye")
```

Comment: you are comparing an `int` (`Number`) to a `str` (`Guess`). ...and on the last line you are overwriting `raw_input` with `'Goodbye'` (which is probably the first thing you must fix).

Comment: `raw_input = ("Goodbye")` replaces the `raw_input` function with the string `"Goodbye"`.  I think you just want `raw_input("Goodbye")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this line from your program:

```
raw_input = ("Goodbye")
```

This line does not invoke the `raw_input()` function. Rather, it rebinds the global name `raw_input` to the string `"Goodbye"`. Since this is the last line of your program, this line has no practical effect.

If you want the program to pause before exiting, try this:

```
raw_input("Goodbye")
```

Comment: Shouldn't s(he) be using `input()`? It looks like Python 3.

Comment: It can't be Python3, author implies that it runs fine up to that point. If it does otherwise run, then the previous usage of `raw_input()` and `input()` indicate Python2. I don't know why author uses the functional notation `print()`.